# Can't figure out logic for this assignment

Tags: python

```
school_days = 15
classes_per_day = 5
total_classes = 75
for counter in range(school_days):
    total_classes = total_classes + classes_per_day

print(total_classes)
```

Here are the instructions in the assignment:

> Task - Change the values stored in the variables school_days, classes_per_day, and total_classes so that the loop calculates the classes for a student that has 15 school days left. The student has 5 classes per day. The final value of total classes should be 75.

Output: 75

I've been trying to figure this out for the last hour, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share the exact code you run ? without the zeros. Because I get 75 with the correct vlaues

Comment: school_days = 15
    classes_per_day = 5
    total_classes = 75

    for counter in range(school_days):
        total_classes = total_classes + classes_per_day

    print(total_classes)

Comment: Don't reply to improvement suggestions with comments: Edit the question.

Comment: did you saw my answer ? Don't set total_classes

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error (which is an error that forbids to run the code by the way) but nothing can happen with zeros

You may set `15` and `5` but not `total_classes` that will contain the result

```
school_days = 15
classes_per_day = 5
total_classes = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but you could try this:

```
school_days = 1
classes_per_day = 0
total_classes = 0
total_classes = total_classes + classes_per_day
for counter in range(school_days):
    print(total_classes + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error try changing the zeros to values like

```
school_days = 10
classes_per_day = 4
```